# Param From must be specified

Tags: twilio

I'm using the sample code from the Twilio at

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

I'm using the Test Account SID and posting successfully:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC6a7b8e409b647ec2ddd7deda20039642/Messages.json
-d "Body=Test%20Message%20For%20Twilio" \
-d 'To=%2B19255195411' \
-d 'From=%2B15005550006' \
-u 'AC6a7b8e409b647ec2ddd7deda20039642:{AuthToken}'
```

I get the error, even though I specify the FROM [the from is the test page (+15005550006 - This number passes all validation.)] :

```
{
    "code":90011,
    "message":"Param From must be specified.",
    "more_info":"twilio url to /docs/errors/90011", (doesn't resolve)
    "status":400
}
```

What is wrong with my format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your command, you are missing a "\" after Messages.json so the API is not receiving any parameters and failing your request.

The following works:

```
   curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC6a7b8e409b647ec2ddd7deda20039642/Messages.json' \
    -d "Body=Test%20Message%20For%20Twilio" \
    -d 'To=%2B19255195411' \
    -d 'From=%2B15005550006' \
    -u 'AC6a7b8e409b647ec2ddd7deda20039642:{AuthToken}'
```